# Laravel NOVA without a primary key makes an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a database that I can't change. When one of the tables has no primary key. this is the module of the table:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//////////////////////////////////////////////
class t_hendtl extends Model
{
    //
    //protected $primaryKey = 'hen_num';

    protected $table = 't_hendtl';

    public $timestamps = false;  

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $primaryKey = null;


}
```

On the nova side I just dont use the ID field. It looks like that:

```
public function fields(Request $request)


 {
        return [
            //ID::make()->sortable(),
            Text::make('Inv number', 'hen_num'),
            Text::make('Inv type', 'hen_type'),
        ];
    }
```

However I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server] An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not alowed. Chane the alias to a valid name. (SQL:select top 26*from[t_hendtl]order by [t_hendtl].[] desc).
```

what do you recommend to do ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally added a column to the table though its a table that other software is using. Otherwise it wont work